# Hölder continuity of Radon transform of smooth function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, sobolev-spaces, integral-transforms, image-processing

Given an integrable function (e.g a probability density function) $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, let $R[f]$ be its Radon transform defined by
$$
R[f](w,b) := \int_{\mathbb R^n} \delta(x^\top w - b)f(x)\,dx,
$$
for every $(w,b) \in \mathbb R^{n+1}$. Here, $\delta$ is the Dirac delta distribution.

> **Question.** *In terms of smoothness of $f$, what is a sufficient condition to ensure that (1) $\|R[f]\|_\infty < \infty$, and (2) there exist constants $\alpha,C \in (0,\infty)$ such that for every $w \in \mathbb R^d$, the function $b \mapsto R[f](w,b)$ is $(\alpha,C)$-Hölder continuous, i.e.,*
> $$
> \big|R[f](w,b')-R[f](w,b)\big| \le C|b'-b|^\alpha,
> \tag{+}
> $$
> *for all $w \in \mathbb R^d$ and $b,b' \in \mathbb R$ ?*

---

**Related:** [Smoothness of Radon transform](https://mathoverflow.net/q/421814/78539)

Comment: You could use Thm 5.1 from Natterers "Math of computerized tomo" which gives that $Rf$ is in the Sobolev space $H^{\alpha + (n-1)/2}$ if $f$ is in $H^\alpha$. Using Sobolev embeddings in $L^\infty$ and Hölder spaces should give some answer.

Comment: @Dirk Thanks for the insight. You mean this book https://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Computerized-Tomography-Classics-Applied/dp/0898714931 ? Do you by any means have an equivalent reference for the result which is freely available (pdf) ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @dohmatob the correct link is [this](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898719284). Most math department can download from SIAM.

Comment: @username Thanks, but I don't have access to SIAM. I'd appreciate an equivalent reference from a math paper published in the open (not behind a paywall), if you know any.

Answer (score 0):

- It turns out that the "correct" domain of definition of the Radon transform is the Schwarz space $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$  of infinitely-differential functions on $\mathbb R^n$ with derivatives which decrease faster than any polynomial.
- Also, it is well-known that for any integer $k$, $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is dense in $H^k(\mathbb R^n)$, the fractional Sobolev space of order $k$. Taking $\alpha \in (0,1)$, we know thanks to **Lemma 1** of Oberlin and Stein (1982) [Mapping Properties of the Radon Transform](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24893225) that, there exists a constant $C_\alpha \in (0,\infty)$ such that for any appropriately integrable function $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, it holds that
  $$
  \sup_{b \in \mathbb R}|\Delta_t g(b)| \le C_\alpha\|g\|_{H^k(\mathbb R)}\cdot |t|^\alpha,
  \tag{1}
  $$
  where $k := \alpha+1/2$ and $\Delta_t g(b) := g(b+t)-g(b)$. Applying (1) with $g = R_w[f]:b \mapsto R[f](w,b)$, for fixed nonzero $w \in \mathbb R^n$, and recalling the *Central Slice Theorem* by which $\widehat{R_w[f]}(s) = \|w\|_2\cdot \widehat{f}(sw)$, we deduce that
  $$
  \frac{|\Delta_t R_w[f](b)|^2}{C_\alpha^2|t|^{2\alpha}} \le \ldots \le \|w\|^{-2\alpha}\|f\|_{H^k(\mathbb R^n)},
  $$
  from which it follows that $R_w[f]$ is Hoelder-continuous of order $\alpha$.